# PHP: how to remove the last line break from the text file?

Tags: php, arrays, text, explode

In a school work, I built a site for a fictional space museum in my city using PHP. It has a Data Inclusion and Data Consultation systems, but I have a problem with the consultation that I want to know how to solve: how to delete the last line break from the file?

### Data Inclusion

In the restricted area of the site, I have a HTML5 form with 5 fields (name, addres, telephone number, sex and visited exhibitions) that sends the data by the method POST to a function in PHP that writes it on a given txt file by using the `fwrite` command:

```
fwrite ($pointer, "$name | $addres | $telephone | $sex | $exhibitions " .PHP_EOL);
```

As you can see, it writes in a txt file the data entered on the form, plus a line break. The pointer is the variable used by `fopen` to open the file that I need to work. Example of output:

> Márcio Aguiar | Belmiro Braga Street | 1234-5678 | M | Planets of Solar System
>   Joana Tobias | Santos Dummont Avenue | 8765-4321 | F | Black Holes, Satellites

### Data Consultation

Then there is a consultation system. It has a loop that runs until the file ends. Inside this loop there is a variable named `$buffer` that gets one line of the txt file each time. It is then `explode`d to create a array named `$lines[$counter]`. To print it nicely, I use a `array_combine` where I join the names of the fields on another array (`$keys`) to the values written in `$lines[$counter]`, and attibutes that to `$combined[$counter]`. Then the loop ends and I use a `print_r` inside `<pre></pre>` to see the data written in `$combined`, while mantaining the spaces and breaks that HTML would otherwise ignore. Here is the code:

```
$keys = array ("Name", "Address", "Telephone", "Sex", "Visited exhibition");
for ($counter=0;!feof($reader);$counter++){
    $buffer = fgets($reader);
    $lines[$counter] = explode(" | ", $buffer);
    $combined[$counter] = array_combine($keys, $lines[$counter]);
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($combined);
echo "</pre>";
```

Example of output:

> ```
>     Array
>     (
>     [0] => Array
>         (
>             [Name] => Márcio Aguiar
>             [Address] => Belmiro Braga Street
>             [Telephone] => 1234-5678
>             [Sex] => M
>             [Visited exhibitions] => Planets of Solar System 
>
>         )
>
>     [1] => Array
>         (
>             [Name] => Joana Tobias
>             [Address] => Santos Dummont Avenue
>             [Telephone] => 8765-4321
>             [Sex] => F
>             [Visited exhibitions] => Black Holes, Satellites 
>
>         )
>
>     [2] => 
>     )
> ```

Here you can see that a `2` Array was created blank. It's caused by the last line, that contains only a line break inserted by the form above. I need to remove this last line break, and only that one, but don't know how. I want to know! Not knowing causes the exhibition of an error when the execution arrive at the `array_combine`, because it's needed that the two arrays have the same number of elements, and `2` is blank. Here the error:

> Warning: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements in E:\Aluno\Documents\Wamp\www\trab_1\area_restrita\consulta.php on line 60

Answer (score 3):

**Original answer:**

To remove a trailing line break from any text, you can use [trim()](http://php.net/trim), however in your case, <strike>you just need to use `fopen` in [append mode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php#refsect1-function.fopen-parameters)</strike>:

```
$handle = fopen("/path/to/file", "a");
```

Then get rid of the `PHP_EOL`:

```
fwrite ($pointer, "$name | $addres | $telephone | $sex | $exhibitions");
```

---

**Edit:** You're right that appending doesn't append to a new line. I was mistaken. So you could use trim() like I mentioned earlier. I created a quick example using `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()` and it appears to do what you want:

```
<?php

$file = 'test.txt';

// Set existing contents (for testing sake)
$orig_contents = "bob | 123 fake street | 1234567890 | yes, please | no\n";
$orig_contents .= "bob | 123 fake street | 1234567890 | yes, please | no\n";
$orig_contents .= "bob | 123 fake street | 1234567890 | yes, please | no\n";
$orig_contents .= "bob | 123 fake street | 1234567890 | yes, please | no\n";
file_put_contents($file, $orig_contents);

// Here is how you could add a single new line with append mode
// Notice the trailing \n
file_put_contents($file, "billy | 456 fake street | 2345678901 | no | yes\n", FILE_APPEND);

// Get contents from the file and remove any trailing line breaks
$contents = trim(file_get_contents($file));

$keys = array ("Name", "Address", "Telephone", "Sex", "Visited exhibition");

// Explode based on the new line character
$lines = explode("\n", $contents);

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $values = explode(" | ", $line);
    $combined[] = array_combine($keys, $values);
}

print_r($combined);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Name] => bob
            [Address] => 123 fake street
            [Telephone] => 1234567890
            [Sex] => yes, please
            [Visited exhibition] => no
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Name] => bob
            [Address] => 123 fake street
            [Telephone] => 1234567890
            [Sex] => yes, please
            [Visited exhibition] => no
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Name] => bob
            [Address] => 123 fake street
            [Telephone] => 1234567890
            [Sex] => yes, please
            [Visited exhibition] => no
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Name] => bob
            [Address] => 123 fake street
            [Telephone] => 1234567890
            [Sex] => yes, please
            [Visited exhibition] => no
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Name] => billy
            [Address] => 456 fake street
            [Telephone] => 2345678901
            [Sex] => no
            [Visited exhibition] => yes
        )

)
```

Comment: I don't know where to use `trim`, can you explain please?

Comment: You don't put `trim` anywhere. Just open the file with append mode as the rest of the answer explains.

Comment: I'm already using `a` on `fopen`. Removing `PHP_EOL` makes the data of different people to be inserted all in one line, but I need the information distributed over many lines, one for each person.

Comment: I saw, but could not understand completely... When you used the line `$contents = trim(file_get_contents($file));` you got the full content of the file by using `file_get_contents()`, removed all the `\n`s by using `trim()` and attributed the result to `$contents`, right?
So why you later used `$lines = explode("\n", $contents);`? I understood that this line divides `$contents` in substrings divided by `\n`s, and attributes this string matrix to `$lines` by using `explode()`... But why use the parameter `\n` on the `explode()` if you already removed all the `\n`s using `trim()`?

Comment: @Anders The reason is because `trim()` removes only the first and last whitespace characters. So if you have `{tab}line one{line break}line two{space}{line break}` it will convert it to `line one{line break}line two`. It does not get rid of *every* line break, only if there is one at the beginning or the end. And I did `explode()` to split the string up into an array with every line being a value in the array so that I could loop over it.

Comment: I just found another interesting function that would work in place of `explode` and the loop: [`strtok`](http://php.net/strtok). You might want to take a look at that one too.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the way you're reading the file. You're testing for EOF before reading from the file. But `feof()` won't be true until you try to read while you're at the end of the file.

Instead, you should test whether `fgets()` returns a line.

```
for ($counter = 0; $buffer = fgets($reader); $counter++) {
    $lines[$counter] = explode(" | ", $buffer);
    $combined[$counter] = array_combine($keys, $lines[$counter]);
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/stoi8K)

To explain further, suppose you have a file with one line in it. When `$counter` is `0`, you call `feof()`, and it returns `false`. So you then read the first line, and add it to `$lines` and `$combined`. Then you increment `$counter` and go back to the beginning of the loop.

When `$counter` is `1`, you call `feof()`. It's still not true, because you haven't tried to read at the end of the file yet. Then you try to read the next line, but there is no line there, `fgets` returns `false` and you assign this to `$buffer`. This is treated as an empty string by `explode()`, so you add an empty array to `$lines` and `$combined`. Then you increment `$counter` and go back to the beginning of the loop.

Then you call `feof()`, and this time it returns `true` because you tried to read at the end of the file on the previous iteration. So the loop ends.

As you can see from the above, even though the file only has 1 line, you end up with 2 entries in your arrays, because you didn't test for EOF until after you read too far.

Comment: I understand now. But changing the loop like you suggested makes it work very strangely... With these 3 items:
>a | b | c | M | def
>1 | 2 | 3 | M | 456 
>56 | 78 | 91 | M | 23 
>
I'm getting this output:
     Array
     (
         [0] => Array
             (
                 [Name] => 1
                 [Address] => 2
                 [Telephone] => 3
                 [Sex] => M
                 [Visited exhibitions] => 456 
     
             )
     
         [1] => 
     )

Comment: Typo: `$lines[counter]` should be `$lines[$counter]`

Comment: You're also missing the close parenthesis for `array_combine`. How is the code even running?

Comment: The typo and missing parenthesis aren't present in the code. They were introduced when I translated the code to post here.

Comment: There's no formatting in comments, so I can't tell what your input and output are. Please update the question with your actual code, the test input, and the output.

Comment: I could not understand what you want me to add... There is already a test input and an output on the question.

Comment: Show the input and output you got when you tried to implement my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to get rid of the last line break in data you pulled from the db ($res) you can use the following snippet

```
for ($i=0; $i <count($res); $i++) {

    // If this is not last item then add items separated by line break
    if($i+1 < count($res)) {
        file_put_contents("file.txt", $res[$i].PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    }
    // If this is the last item, then don't append the final line break
    else {
        file_put_contents("file.txt", $res[$i], FILE_APPEND);
    }
}
```